# Can't click elements under Material-UI Popover's backdrop when it's open

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I can't get this behavior with Material-UI's Popover component.

I have this code example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/88z3nq96jl
Steps to see the problem:

1. When I click on Filter1 button, the popover shows up.
2. Then, when I click on Filter2 button, Filter1's popover closes.
3. Then, I need to click another time to get Filter2's popover to show up.

But I don't want to click twice when one of the popover is open, I'd need it to close the previous one and open the proper one at the same time.

I think the backdrop is stopping click events from propagating, so the filter behind it gets never clicked.  Is there a way I can avoid that?

Comment: I have the same issue, can't click on anything while the popover is open. didn't found any solution for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the Material UI's [Popper](https://material-ui.com/utils/popper/) is suitable for your case, from the documentation:

> The scroll and click away aren't blocked like with the Popover
>   component. The placement of the popper updates with the available area
>   in the viewport.

**Demo**:

[image: Edit Material UI popper]

Answer (score 11):

I'm using Material UI 4.11 and React 16.13.

You can set disableEnforceFocus to true (prevent the clicks from being blocked) and disable pointer events on the root css (allow clicks to pass through the backdrop).

```
    const styles = makeStyles<Theme>((theme) => ({
        popover: {
          pointerEvents: "none",
        },
    }));


    <Popover  
      classes={{ root: classes.popover}}
      disableEnforceFocus={true}
    >
    </Popover>
```

Comment: I tried this, but since the backdrop is not clicked the first Popover does not close anymore.